# C: sizeof struct of structs to find number of elements in struct

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have two structs:

```
struct point {
  double x;
  double y;
  const char *description;
};

struct geomap {
  struct point points[];
};
```

Let's say I add x points into a new map. How do I get that number x starting from sizeof? Or is there any other way to know how many points did I add into a new map? I would need a loop to remove points and do other stuff, but I cannot figure the number of element out.

I tried

```
sizeof(m->points[])/sizeof(m->points[0])
```

But it says: ERR expected expression
Some code if you want to play around quicker:

```
static int counter = 0;

struct geomap *geomap_new() {
  struct geomap *a_geomap = (struct geomap *)malloc(sizeof(geomap));
  if (!a_geomap)
    exit(0);
  struct point *a_point = (struct point *)malloc(sizeof(point));
  if (!a_point)
    exit(0);
  return a_geomap;
}

int geomap_add_point(struct geomap *m, double x, double y, const char *descr) {
  m->points[counter].x = x;
  m->points[counter].y = y;
  m->points[counter].description = descr;
  counter++;
  if (!m) {
    printf("failed to allocate new point");
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  struct geomap *m = geomap_new();
  geomap_add_point(m, 10324, 2341213.2, "212222");
  geomap_add_point(m, 103212, 221341.2, "21wdd2");
  geomap_add_point(m, 103241, 2.2, "2213122");
  geomap_add_point(m, 1034123, 23341.2, "1111");
  geomap_add_point(m, 1000324213, 23234242341.2, "dediowd");

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well in this example there are always 0 points in the struct. Despite the fact there are 0 points in the struct, your code writes to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th points, thus overwriting some memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: What is this  `struct point *a_point = ...` for?

Comment: Many thanks everyone for the answers, they were all very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a minimum reproducable example.

You have some errors/typos.

Error #1:

```
/* ... */
struct geomap *a_geomap = (struct geomap *)malloc(sizeof(geomap));
/* ... */
struct point *a_point = (struct point *)malloc(sizeof(point));
/* ... */
```

Here you trying to allocate array of points inside geomap, right? See `malloc(/*size in bytes*/)`. Guess this code should be something like:

```
int i = 0;
/* ... */
struct geomap *a_geomap = (struct geomap *)malloc(sizeof(struct geomap));
a_geomap->points = (struct point *)malloc(sizeof(struct point) * /* Maximum number of points here */ )
/* ... */
```

Error #2:

```
int geomap_add_point(struct geomap *m, double x, double y, const char *descr) {
  m->points[counter].x = x;
  m->points[counter].y = y;
  m->points[counter].description = descr;
  counter++;
  if (!m) {
    printf("failed to allocate new point");
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

You should check here if you exceeded size of the array. Otherwise you may get SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault). Should be something:

```
int geomap_add_point(struct geomap *m, double x, double y, const char *descr) {
  if (!m) {
    printf("No geomap!!!");
    return -1;
  }
  // Here check for size
  if (counter >= /* Maximum number of points here */) {
    printf("No space for new point!!!");
    return -1;
  }
  m->points[counter].x = x;
  m->points[counter].y = y;
  m->points[counter].description = descr;
  ++counter;
  return 0;
}
```

And finally...

Warning #1:

You should consider common practice where usualy we return from function **negative value** on error and **zero** on success.

P.S. Short answer: if you have a static array, than `count = (sizeof(/*array*/) / sizeof(/*element type*/))` should work.
**BUT!**
This will newer work with dynamic arrays. Dynamic arrays only `cound = /*Number of elements*/`.

Example:

```
/* For static array: */

#define MAX_ARR_T_DATA_SIZE 100
/* ... */
struct arr_t {
  int data[MAX_ARR_T_DATA_SIZE];
};
/* ... */
arr_t array;
int count = sizeof(struct array) / sizeof(int);


/* For dynamic array: */

#define MAX_ARR_T_DATA_SIZE 100
/* ... */
struct arr_t {
  int* data;
};
/* ... */
arr_t array;
array.data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_ARR_T_DATA_SIZE);
int count = MAX_ARR_T_DATA_SIZE;
```

P.P.S. Also I suggest you to read about dynamic arrays. This for example:
[http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html)

Comment: Re “You are not allowed to allocate array like that. You need to specify size”: The C standard permits defining an array in a structure type as `struct point points[];`. It must be the last member, and there must be at least one other named member. Memory for such structures can be allocated dynamically, and the structure will behave as if it contained an array as large as the allocated memory will allow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, sorry. My mistake. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should consider if an array is the right data type to use for this container. If you plan to add/remove items frequently, then a linked list or a graph might be more suitable.

As for `struct point points[];`, this is a so-called *flexible array member*. It can only be placed at the end of a struct and the struct needs to have other members beside it. A flexible array member is to be regarded as an array of incomplete type, so you can't use `sizeof` on it because the size isn't known at compile-time. You have to keep track of the size manually.

Correct use would be something like this:

```
struct geomap {
  size_t size;
  struct point points[];
};

struct geomap *geomap_new(size_t def_size) {
  struct geomap *obj = malloc( sizeof *obj + sizeof(struct point[def_size]) );
  obj->size = def_size;
  ...
```

That is, you allocate memory for the object and the flexible array in one go.

Answer (score 0):

In this example there are always 0 points in the struct.

Despite the fact there are 0 points in the struct, your code writes to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th points, thus overwriting some memory that doesn't belong to you.

So you can get the number of points by using the number `0`.

If you want to allocate a map with some points in it, you can do so like this:

```
struct geomap *a_geomap = (struct geomap *)malloc(sizeof(geomap) + NUMBER_OF_POINTS*sizeof(point));
```

It is up to you to decide how to store `NUMBER_OF_POINTS`. You could decide that it's always 10, for example. Or you could add another `int` to `struct geomap` to store the number.

Note that arrays cannot be resized after they're created. Ever.

Comment: "Note that arrays cannot be resized after they're created. Ever."  In this case you can simply realloc. Not the most efficient way, but perfectly possible.

Comment: @Lundin realloc allocates a new array which may or may not have the same address as the old one